# React-Kotlin wrapper setState method

Tags: kotlin

On the react docs here:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

It says that the following code is unsafe to use because state is updated asynchronously:

```
this.setState({
  counter: this.state.counter + this.props.increment,
});
```

And instead to pass in the previous state and props like this:

```
this.setState(function(prevState, props) {
  return {
    counter: prevState.counter + props.increment
  };
});
```

However, the React-Kotlin wrapper located here:

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-fullstack-sample/tree/master/frontend/src/org/jetbrains/react

Has the state change passed in as an extension function of state, which modifies the variables on the state object:

```
//Located in the ReactComponent class in ReactComponent.kt
fun setState(builder: S.() -> Unit) {
    ...
}
```

If I call `setState` function like this in Kotlin:

```
setState {
    counter: state.counter + props.increment
}
```

Isn't that equivalent to the unsafe method above? Wouldn't it need to be implemented like this in the React-Kotlin wrapper?

```
fun setState(builder: S.(prevState: S, props: P) -> Unit) {
    ...
}
```

And then called like this?

```
setState { prevState, props ->
    counter: prevState.counter + props.increment
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at create-react-kotlin-app source code you will find this comment before setState invocation:
"actually, the operation is performed on a state's copy, so it stays effectively immutable".

https://github.com/JetBrains/create-react-kotlin-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/src/ticker/Ticker.kt

That's it, kotlin copies state and pass copy as receiver to setState method. So, instead of "counter: state.counter + props.increment"' you should write "counter = counter + props.increment".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the result of a setState, then you have to call setState(newState, callback).

Probably, this React binding is doing more than just a wrapper over react. I think that the react is a facade over the real react.